# ValueError with pandastable row coloring

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I'm using `pandastable` to visualize a Dataframe and I want to highlight certain rows. In the `pandastable` documentation I found the function `setRowColors`. It says there to use color in hex. But when I'm applying the code I get the following error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '#ff3300'

With this code I'm reproducing the error:

```
import tkinter as tk
from pandastable import Table 
import pandas as pd

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root) 
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

df = pd.DataFrame() 
df["column1"] = [1,2,3] 
df["column2"] = ["a","b","c"]


pt = Table(frame, dataframe=df) 
pt.setRowColors(rows=1, clr="#ff3300", cols="all") 
pt.redraw() 
pt.show()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the current implementation in version `0.12.2` of the `setRowColors` function, the `rows` parameter must be passed a `list` of values:

```
import tkinter as tk

import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["column1"] = [1, 2, 3]
df["column2"] = ["a", "b", "c"]

pt = Table(frame, dataframe=df)
# rows=list of values
pt.setRowColors(rows=[1], clr='#ff3300', cols="all")
# No need to redraw it is done within the setRowColors function
pt.show()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: tkinter window with coloured rows]

There is an open issue for this on github [Setting colour of cell in dataframe](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable/issues/197)

---

The reason this happens is because of the way that the index is subset, and the way that [Series.at](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.at.html) modifies column dtypes depending on if it is accessing a cell or a group of cells.

This `pandas` code reproduces the error:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": [1, 2, 3], "column2": ["a", "b", "c"]})
rc = pd.DataFrame()
rc['column1'] = pd.Series(np.nan, index=df.index)
idx = df.index[1]  # <- uses int
print(idx)  # 1  # (python int)
rc.at[idx, 'column1'] = '#ff3300'
print(rc)
```

Producing:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '#ff3300'
```

However the following works as expected:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": [1, 2, 3], "column2": ["a", "b", "c"]})
rc = pd.DataFrame()
rc['column1'] = pd.Series(np.nan, index=df.index)
idx = df.index[[1]]  # <- uses list
print(idx)  # Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')  # (pandas Index object)
rc.at[idx, 'column1'] = '#ff3300'
print(rc)
```

```
   column1
0      NaN
1  #ff3300
2      NaN
```

---

This occurs in the `setRowColors` function in version `0.12.2` [source code](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable/blob/f782337cc1dea4ef1cd6d21f6d71f04bb553f37b/pandastable/core.py#L588-L616):

```
def setRowColors(self, rows=None, clr=None, cols=None):
    """Set rows color from menu.
    Args:
        rows: row numbers to be colored
        clr: color in hex
        cols: column numbers, can also use 'all'
    """

    if clr is None:
        clr = pickColor(self, '#dcf1fc')
    if clr == None:
        return
    if rows == None:
        rows = self.multiplerowlist
    df = self.model.df
    idx = df.index[rows]  # <- The issue is here (idx becomes an int if not a list)
    rc = self.rowcolors
    if cols is None:
        cols = self.multiplecollist
    elif cols is 'all':
        cols = range(len(df.columns))
    colnames = df.columns[cols]
    for c in colnames:
        if c not in rc.columns:
            rc[c] = pd.Series(np.nan, index=df.index)
        # rc[c][idx] = clr
        rc.at[idx, c] = clr
    self.redraw()
    return
```

*Comment marking the line at issue is added for clarity